# When exactly patents fall under double-patenting?

Tags: claims, double-patenting

I have an omnibus specification and I want to split it into multiple patents at a later point. I'm little afraid that accidentally I'll double patent my work.

So I just need some clarification.

I have Patent A, B, C.

Patent A is the main patent. It contains step X and Y.

Patent B is a derivative patent that relies on Patent A functionality. The steps will look like W, X, Y, Z

Patent C also a derivative patent that relies on Patent A functionality. The steps will look like U, X, Y, Z

Since B and C claims contains Patent A claims, does this considered as double-patenting?

Comment: What exactly is the point of having multiple patents with the same claims?

Comment: @EricShain I'm not gonna have multiple patents with same claims. Each patent deals with different inventive concepts. But as I said, patent B and C relies on patent A.  Patent A is the core inventive concept. Patent B and C are derivative inventive concepts. Each patent gonna use at least 100 pages.

Comment: I fear you are trying to write your own patents without help from a patent attorney. In my opinion, that’s not a recipe for success.

Comment: @EricShain You are right. At this point, I can't able to afford patent attorney for all my patents. I hired a patent firm. But they said they can help me with only one inventive concept for the amount I have. For the rest I have to do it on my own. I know that is a very bad idea. But I have no other choice at this moment. I don't want to lose my priority date since a big company trying to rip off my many years of work. As they say, something is better than nothing.

Comment: You might consider an independent patent agent rather than a firm (it you are filing a US application). They are usually cheaper. You really shouldn't need 100 pages to describe an invention.

Comment: This question and answer from yesterday is relevant: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20663/repeating-claims-in-a-cip-that-are-identical-to-those-in-the-parent-application

Comment: @EricShain Thanks. But it's already too late for me. Actually my invention consists of around 300 pages. I have been working on this since 2013. So it contains plenty of ideas I figured during those years. I think there will be at least 6 unique inventive concepts in those 300 pages. As of now I'm gonna file a single PCT application to defer the filing costs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96534/discussion-between-giri-and-eric-shain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you say "patents B and C *contain* patent A's claims". That is not the case in your example. They build upon the information taught in patent A.

The issue will be whether the claims in B and C are obvious variants from the teachings embodied in the claims of patent A. We can't tell that from "W, X, Y, Z". If adding step W at the start and adding Z to the end of the steps is not an obvious variant of X, Y there is no double patenting.

If an examiner asserts that there is a non-statutory double patenting issue, you can argue, amend, or sign a terminal disclaimer. In a terminal disclaimer you get the multiple patents but agree that when one expires they all expire and that they will always be commonly owned.